# Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 111 : Error Beacuse of {} in URI

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-zuul

I identified the error is because of below Curly Braces in the URI 
`{2019-06-11T00:00:00%20TO%202019-06-11T23:59:59}`

I also tried adding the `FilterRegistrationBean`, but it didn't work

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean() {
    FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
    characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(false);
    characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    characterEncodingFilter.setForceRequestEncoding(false);
    characterEncodingFilter.setForceResponseEncoding(false);
    registrationBean.setFilter(characterEncodingFilter);
    registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
    return registrationBean;
}




private static class EmbeddedTomcatCustomizer implements 
        WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> {

    @Override
    public void customize(TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory) {
        factory.addConnectorCustomizers((TomcatConnectorCustomizer) connector -> {
            connector.setAttribute("relaxedPathChars", "<>[\\]^`:{|}");
            connector.setAttribute("relaxedQueryChars", "<>[\\]^`:{|}");
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The safest option is to encode `{` and `}` using [percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) as `%7B` and `%7D`. As per [RFC-1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738#page-3) these two characters are considered unsafe and can cause problem when being processed:

> Unsafe:

> Characters can be unsafe for a number of reasons.  The space
> character is unsafe because significant spaces may disappear and
> insignificant spaces may be introduced when URLs are transcribed or
> typeset or subjected to the treatment of word-processing programs.
> The characters "<" and ">" are unsafe because they are used as the
> delimiters around URLs in free text; the quote mark (""") is used to
> delimit URLs in some systems.  The character "#" is unsafe and should
> always be encoded because it is used in World Wide Web and in other
> systems to delimit a URL from a fragment/anchor identifier that might
> follow it.  The character "%" is unsafe because it is used for
> encodings of other characters.  **Other characters are unsafe because
> gateways and other transport agents are known to sometimes modify
> such characters. These characters are "{", "}", "|", "", "^", "~",
> "[", "]", and "`".**
>
> All unsafe characters must always be encoded within a URL. For
> example, the character "#" must be encoded within URLs even in
> systems that do not normally deal with fragment or anchor
> identifiers, so that if the URL is copied into another system that
> does use them, it will not be necessary to change the URL encoding.

Comment: Thanks for the response 
But i believe it should be handle by client, is there any possible server can encode the {} %7B and %7D